# Gatsby installation in Windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, graphql, gatsby

I am working on windows 10.
I am trying to install gatsby, and I thought I did, but when I run gatsby -v in VM Code, something goes wrong.

```
/mnt/c/Users/mmkob/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/prettier/third-party.js:9863
      for await (const place of this.config.searchPlaces) {
          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/mmkob/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/prettier/index.js:16652:18)
```

I am not quite sure what to do with this. I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Node version up to `v10`. As you can see in the [`for await...of` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of), the syntax `for await (const place of this.config.searchPlaces)` it's available in versions greater than `10.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use nvm use  to switch to a higher version of node. in my case i switch to 14.16. so just do nvm use 14.16 if you have it installed. You should install a higher version later than 10.0.0